# CakePHP capture fields that were updated

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have the following input fields in one of the edit forms:

```
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('customer_nr');
        echo $this->Form->input('name',array('id'=>'customer_name'));
        echo $this->Form->input('phone');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
?>
```

In the controller I just check if the request is post/put and save that single row.

What I want to do is to capture which fields have been changed. That is needed for giving different flash messages.

I have been through cake php documentation, but did not find any behaviour for this issue.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check, if data from form and from database are different, then:

```
$data = $this->ModelName->findById($id);
if($this->request->data != $data){
    //array was changed
}
```

If you need to know, which array key is different, then:

```
$data = $this->ModelName->findById($id);
$data = $this->ModelName->findById($id);
$difference = array_diff($data, $this->request->data)
```

Is that what you need?